# Claim augmentation with Azure AD authentcation

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

"I have an application where I have users authenticated with multiple directories all federated using a ADFS. There is a central ADFS that does the federated and routing to the correct IDP. Most IDP are ADFS that add claims  to the SAML token by using the normal ADFS rules. We now have some customers that want to use Azure AD as IDP, but this seems not to allow to add claims like ADFS.
 
What would be the way to add custom claims to a saml token using Azure AD?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding your application in Azure AD Directory Portal via the Application Gallery. This gives you the opportunity to add claims to the outgoing SAML Token.

If you have Azure AD Premium you can add your own application (that accept SAML 2.0) and configure the extra claims via the "Attributes tab"

If you or your customers do not have Azure AD Premium you will have to have you app added to the Azure AD Application Gallery. The process for this is described in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-app-gallery-listing/